# Diving the result of an arc4random_unifrom gives me 0

Tags: swift, arc4random

I am trying to create a decimal between 0 and 1 so I am creating an Int between 0 and 10000 then dividing it by 10000 (an Int) to get the decimal.

```
AtBatResult = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(10000)))
```

This line of code gives me number which is fine.

```
AtBatResult = AtBatResult / Int(10000)
```

When I run this line of code however, the number becomes 0 no matter what. What is happening here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Convert AtBatResult to decimal before dividing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared `atBatResult` to be an `Int`. You can't assign a decimal value to it. And you are doing integer division.

You need a `Double` variable and you need to do decimal division.

Here's one way:

```
let atBatResult = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(10000)))
let finalResult = Double(atBatResult) / 10000
```

Or you can do:

```
let atBatResult = Double(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(10000))) / 10000
```

This will make `atBatResult` a `Double` instead of an `Int`.

FYI - it is standard naming convention to start method and variable names with lowercase letters. Class names start with uppercase.

Comment: I got the result "Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'Int'"

Comment: On which of the two lines I posted? I don't get that problem with the code in my answer.

Comment: Now it's working, I had declared the var before as an Int that is why. Thanks!